# ng serve behind traefik proxy don't load app in docker container

Tags: angular, docker, traefik

i'm creating apps in [nx.dev](https://nx.dev/) workspace, and use docker to have local dev environement.

I have many Nestjs apps working fine, but my first Angular apps did not.

My goal is to accès my angular in my browser on this url : http://localhost/admin

**Traefik config**

```yaml
http:
  services:
    admin-app:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: http://admin-app:4200
  routers:
    admin-app:
      rule: PathPrefix(`/admin`, `/admin/.*`)
      service: admin-app
```

**NX project config**

```json
{
  "name": "admin-app",
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
  "projectType": "application",
  "prefix": "boite-a-outils",
  "sourceRoot": "apps/admin-app/src",
  "tags": [],
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "options": {
        "baseHref": "/admin",                    // add baseHref for build
        "outputPath": "dist/apps/admin-app",
        "index": "apps/admin-app/src/index.html",
        "main": "apps/admin-app/src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": ["zone.js"],
        "tsConfig": "apps/admin-app/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          "apps/admin-app/src/favicon.ico",
          "apps/admin-app/src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": ["apps/admin-app/src/styles.less"],
        "scripts": []
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "500kb",
              "maximumError": "1mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "2kb",
              "maximumError": "4kb"
            }
          ],
          "outputHashing": "all"
        },
        "development": {
          "buildOptimizer": false,
          "optimization": false,
          "vendorChunk": true,
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "sourceMap": true,
          "namedChunks": true
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "production"
    },
    "serve": {
      "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "admin-app:build:production"
        },
        "development": {
          "browserTarget": "admin-app:build:development",
          "host": "0.0.0.0",                              // tell webpack to listen on all interfaces inside container
          "publicHost": "http://localhost/admin",         // support for traefik proxy
          "servePath": "/admin"                           // path from where app will be serve
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "development"
    },
// after config contains only test and lint config untouch for now
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>admin-app</title>
    <base href="/admin" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <boite-a-outils-root></boite-a-outils-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

When i trie to open http://localhost/admin in my browser, index.html load well, but all `.js .css` end in 404 not found error.

In the chrome dev tools i can see that all 404 try to find file in the wrong place.
Exemple with the css file, i expect this url :
`http://localhost/admin/styles.css` (test in my browser work's fine)
but instead index.html call :
`http://localhost/styles.css`

I don't understand if it's my build ou serve configuration that is wrong.

Thanks for your help